# Multi-page tables in html2fpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I am facing problem of page break in HTML.

I have static as well dynamic data for creating PDF using html2fpdf script. When I have more than 25 rows in table then page gets break and messed up.

How will I put page break in my HTML or PHP code so html2fpdf script take consider it as page break?

Comment: Have you considered DOMPDF? It handles multi page tables nicely.

Comment: have a look at fpdf vs tcpdf !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117788/page-break-in-html2pdf

Comment: Try this https://bytescout.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=62&nav=0,1,3

Answer (score 1):

html2pdf will break - it the single  content goes beyond specified page type ( default A4 ) ..
I have checked with  only e.g. content with 50 lines including recursive tables etc

what you can do is restructure your html code in a way that not a single  which holds actual content - does not hold bigger content...

e.g.

```
<table><tr><td>content for header</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>content for part 1</td></tr></table>

<table><tr>
<td>first line of content</td>
--- you can have as many lines here but content of single line should not be more than A4 size
<td>1000th line of content</td>
</tr></table>
```

--- Hope this helps