# html2pdf page-break-after creating issue

Tags: php, html2pdf

I want to create new page using css property "page-break-after". I have followed all steps given on [Page break in Html2Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117788/page-break-in-html2pdf) but getting following error.

[image]
[image]

As you can see... 2nd page is starting from where first page ended.. I want 2nd page to start from top.

```
<?
/*
Template Name: View Form
*/

include_once(ABSPATH."connection/localhost.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."include/cls_forms.php");
include_once(ABSPATH."include/cls_fields.php");
//Authenticate("U");

$oFields = new Fields;
$oForm = new Forms;

$Title = $oForm->getFormTitleByID($_GET['form_id']);
$Content = $oForm->getFormContentByID($_GET['form_id']);
$isPleading = $oForm->getFormTypeByID($_GET['form_id']);


$FieldValues = $oForm->getUserFormFields($_SESSION['user_id'], $_GET['distinct_id']);

foreach($FieldValues as $Name => $Value)
{
    $Content = str_replace("«".$Name."»", "<b>".$Value."</b>", $Content);
}

function filterMsWord($Content)
{
    $Content = preg_replace("<([A-Za-z0-9\/]*):([A-Za-z0-9-\"=: ]*)>", "", $Content);
    $Content = str_replace("<>", "", $Content);
    return $Content;
}

if ($_GET['type'] == 'doc')
    $Content = str_replace("[---pagebreak---]", '<br clear=all style="mso-special-character:line-break; page-break-before:always">', $Content);
elseif ($_GET['type'] == 'pdf')
    $Content = str_replace("[---pagebreak---]", "<div class='page-break-before'></div><div class='page-break'></div>", $Content);
else
    $Content = str_replace("[---pagebreak---]", "<div class='page-break'></div>", $Content);

if ($_GET['type'] == 'doc')
{
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".$Title.".doc");
}
else if ($_GET['type'] == 'pdf')
{
    require_once(ABSPATH.'pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    ob_start();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Preview Form</title>
<style>
.pleading-paper-size {
    width: 6.35in !important;
    max-width: 8.5in !important;
    <? if ($_GET['type'] != 'pdf' and $_GET['type'] != 'doc') {?>  
        background-image: url(../images/pleading.jpg);
        background-position: -0.5in 0;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    <? } ?>
    padding-left: 1in !important;
    padding-right: 1in !important;
    <? if ($_GET['type'] != 'pdf') { ?>  
    line-height: 0.3242in !important;
    <? } ?>  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.normal {
    width: <? if (!isset($_GET['type'])) { ?>6.0<? } else if ($_GET['type'] == 'doc') { ?>6.5<? } else { ?>5.0<? } ?>in !important;
    text-align: left;
}
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    clear:both;
}
page-break-before {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    clear:both;
}
p, td {
    margin: 0 !important;
    text-indent: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
@media print {
.pleading-paper-size {
    background-image: none;
}
}
</style>
<? if (isset($_GET['preview'])) { ?>
<script language="javascript">
    function clearData(){
        window.clipboardData.setData('text','') 
    }
    function cldata(){
        if(clipboardData){
            clipboardData.clearData();
        }
    }
    setInterval("cldata();", 1000);
</script>
<? $Body = ' ondragstart="return false;" onselectstart="return false;"  oncontextmenu="return false;" onload="clearData();" onblur="clearData();" style="background-image: url('.ABSPATH.'images/PREVIEW.png);"';
} ?>
</head>

<body <?=$Body?>>
<? if (isset($_GET['preview'])) { ?>
  <table class="<? if ($isPleading) { ?>pleading-paper-size<? } else { ?>normal<? } ?>" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="javascript: window.history.back()">
        <input name="continue" type="button" value="Go Back" style="font-size:24px" />
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../addons/?distinct_id=<?=$_GET['distinct_id']?>">
        <input name="continue" type="button" value="Continue to Next Step" style="font-size:24px" />
        </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<? } ?>
<div class="<? if ($isPleading) { ?>pleading-paper-size<? } else { ?>normal<? } ?>">
<?=filterMsWord($Content)?>
</div>
<? if (isset($_GET['preview'])) { ?>
  <table class="<? if ($isPleading) { ?>pleading-paper-size<? } else { ?>normal<? } ?>" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="javascript: window.history.back()">
        <input name="continue" type="button" value="Go Back" style="font-size:24px" />
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../addons/?distinct_id=<?=$_GET['distinct_id']?>">
        <input name="continue" type="button" value="Continue to Next Step" style="font-size:24px" />
        </a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <? } ?>
</body>
</html>
<?
if ($_GET['type'] == 'pdf')
{
    try
    {
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($html, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        $html2pdf->Output($Title.'.pdf', 'D');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you share your php code

Comment: i have updated my question with php code

Comment: $_GET['vuehtml'] contains all html ?? then why don't you use DOM object, explain.

Comment: no $_GET['vuehtml'] is just a flag of debugging mode.

Comment: are you using PAGE-BREAK-AFTER ? this is not your complete code, i am not able to identify your problem without viewing your all code.@Mustafa Mansoor

Comment: I have updated my full code.

Answer (score 5):

Use **page** tags.

ex.

```
<page>
 content here.
</page>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that you have to redefine `page_header` and `page_footer` within each `<page>`.

Answer (score 1):

IN html2fpdf.php

search this:

```
switch($tag){
  case 'PAGE_BREAK': //custom-tag
  case 'NEWPAGE': //custom-tag
      $this->blockjustfinished = true;
      $this->AddPage();
      break;
```

You see you can use `<NEWPAGE>` tag which define new page or page break

I use `"<NEWPAGE>"`  it works correctly.

I use `'HTML2FPDF_VERSION','3.0(beta)'`

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
```

instead of

```
<page>
```

you should also add `$this->parsingCss->setPosition();` in `_tag_close_DIV` method:

```
protected function _tag_close_DIV($param, $other='div')
    {
        if($this->parsingCss->value['page-break-after'] == "always") {
            $this->_setNewPage(null, '', null, $this->_defaultTop);
            $this->parsingCss->setPosition();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and have tried using page-break-before as well as page-break-after, both using the DIV tag. It appears that HTML2pdf class is not resetting the vertical start point of the next line of text, after the page break occurs.

Sample code:

```
(code for first page here)

// Supplement Schedule invoice page
$htmlfile[] = "<div style=\"page-break-before:always\"></div>";
$htmlfile[] = "<h1 style=\"text-align:center; margin-bottom:0; \">Supplement Estimate</h1>";
$htmlfile[] = "<h4 style=\"text-align:center; margin:0\">($visit->next_visit Weeks)</h4>";
[more code]
```

Sample code using **page** tag to insert page break:

```
(code for first page here)

// Supplement Schedule invoice page
$htmlfile[] = "<page>";
$htmlfile[] = "<h1 style=\"text-align:center; margin-bottom:0; \">Supplement Estimate</h1>";
$htmlfile[] = "<h4 style=\"text-align:center; margin:0\">($visit->next_visit Weeks)</h4>";
[more code/text on the page]
$htmlfile[] = "</page>";
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I was trying to let you know that I'm in the same boat as you and letting you know what *I've* tried. I wrote to the developer but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: I was told to use the <page> tag. I tried it. Put <page> at the desired page break location and then </page> at the end of the page. The code above would change like in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

consider  `pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all'}`, below is the sample option

```
 var opt = {
        margin: 1, //top, left, buttom, right
        filename: 'Initial_Contract.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: {scale:2 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
        pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all', after: '.avoidThisRow' }

    };
```