# HTML2PDF row table cannot page-break

Tags: html, css, html2pdf

I used HTML2PDF version 4.03 for export data to PDF, my problem is when the data format on table rows (tr) always not break to next-page and if content more than height page the content out of tr table.

I have tried this [page break trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117788/page-break-in-html2pdf), but still does not work, please give me solutions.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: table cannot page-break 1]

Here is my CSS:

```css
    body {width:100%;height:auto; }
    hr {border-width:0.3px; border-color:#000; margin:8px 0;}
    h1, h2, h3 {margin:0 0 0 0;}
    h1 {text-transform: uppercase;}
    h2 {font-size:20px;text-transform: uppercase;}
    h3 {font-size:16px;}
    div {font-size:15px;height:auto;}
    p {margin:7px 0;}
    .mb0 {margin-bottom:0px!important;}
    .mb20 {margin-bottom:20px!important;}
    .mt0 {margin-top:0px!important;}
    .centered {
        text-align:center;
    }
    .header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header h1 {font-size:25px;}
    .w40 {
        float:left;
        width:38%;
        margin-left:2%;
        margin:10px 0;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
    }
    .w60 {
        float:left;
        width:58%;
        margin-right:2%;
        margin:10px 0;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
    }
    .w100 {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
    }
    .logo {
        width:75%;
        padding:2px;
    }
    table td {
        padding:3px 0;
    }
    .clearfix {
        clear:both;
        margin:0;
    }
    .sk h3{
        margin-bottom:5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    label {
        margin:0px 0 50px;
        font-size:14px;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tgl-sah {
        position:absolute;left:77px;top:-5px;font-size:13px;color:#143754;font-weight:bold;
    }
    .w530 {
        width:530px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .sub-h3 {margin:7px 0;}
```

And here is HTML

```html
<table class="tb-partai" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th style="border-left:none;width:250px">partai Politik</th>
    <th style="border-left:none;width:170px;">Struktur<br/>Kepengurusan</th>
    <th style="border-left:none;width:170px">Kantor Pusat</th>
    <th style="border-left:none;width:235px">Riwayat Permohonan</th>
   </tr>
<?php 
 $no = 0;
 foreach($partai->result_array() as $p) { 
  $no = $no + 1;
  if($no % 2 == 1) {
   echo "<tr style='background:#FFF'>";
  } else {
   echo "<tr style='background:#EFF1FF'>";
  }
  $sk_last = $this->db->select('*');
  $sk_last = $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
  $sk_last = $this->db->limit(1);
  $sk_last = $this->db->get_where('rz_riwayat_parpol', array('id_parpol'=>$p['id']));
  foreach($sk_last->result_array() as $sk) { ?>

    <td class="t-center"><?php echo $no; ?>.</td>
    <td style="border-left:none;width:265px">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td style="width:125px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$sk['logo']; ?>"></td>
       <td style="padding-left:5px;">
      <?php   echo "<h2>".$sk['nama_parpol']."</h2>";
        echo "<p style='margin:3px 0'>".$sk['alias_parpol']."</p>";?>
        <p style="margin:3px 0">Didirikan : <?php echo dateIndo(GetValue('rz_parpol',$sk['id_parpol'],'tgl_didirikan'));?></p>
        <?php if($sk['status'] == "Berbadan Hukum") { ?>
        <div style="width:165px;position:relative">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/bg-badanhukum.png'; ?>">
        <span class="bdn-hukum" style="margin-left:45px"><?php echo dateIndo($sk['tgl_disahkan']);?></span>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style="border-left:none;max-width:170px">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Ketua Umum</td><td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $sk['ketum']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Sek. Jenderal</td><td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $sk['sekjend']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Bend. Umum</td><td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td><td><?php echo $sk['bendum']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Ketua MA</td><td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td><td style="width:90px;"><?php echo $sk['ketua_ma']; ?></td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Anggota MA</td><td>&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td><td></td></tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="3" style="width:185px"><table><?php echo anggota_ma($sk['anggota_ma'])."</table>"; ?></td></tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td style="border-left:none;width:170px"><?php echo $sk['kantor_pusat']; ?></td>
  <?php } ?>
    <td style="border-left:none;width:350px;text-align:justify">
  <?php $sk_partai = $this->db->get_where('rz_riwayat_parpol', array('id_parpol'=>$p['id']));
     $nomor = 0;
     foreach($sk_partai->result_array() as $skp) {
     $nomor = $nomor + 1;
      echo "<table>
        <tr><td style='width:15px;padding-bottom:8px;'>".$nomor.".</td><td style='width:335px;padding-bottom:8px;line-height:20px'>
         <b>".getValue('rz_srt_masuk', $skp['id_srt_permohonan'], 'no_kendali')."</b> - <span style='color:#323B7E;'>".dateIndo(getValue('rz_srt_masuk', $skp['id_srt_permohonan'], 'tgl_srt'))."</span> <br/>".getValue('rz_srt_masuk', $skp['id_srt_permohonan'], 'perihal')."</td></tr></table>";
     } ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
  </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: In which framework are you using Html2PDF.

Comment: ups sory, HTML code was updated