# Page break in Itext7 in method htmltopdf

Tags: c#, page-break, itext7

I have a problem with generating a page break in the Itext7. Environnement:

1. Visual Studio 2017 C#
2. Version itext7 core: 7.0.2.2 [Trial License atm]
3. Version itext7.pdfhtml: 1.0.0.2

**Flow to generate my PDF:**

1. Use of RazorEngine to parse my model with my cshtml
2. Create a doc and writer
3. Use of `iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(msHtml, writer);` => mshtml is the memory of my generated html in step 1

**Stackoverflow Questions i've tested**

<strike>Suggested solution 1:</strike> 
 is for php...
[Page break in Html2Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117788/page-break-in-html2pdf)
=>not planning on changing my nuget package

<strike>Suggested solution 2:</strike> 
 is for php...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773395/5625156 => not working => are there any restrictions where to use these tags? Can you use them inside a div ,...?

Suggested solution 3:
Use `page-break-before: always`: Worked in itext5 but not in the itext7

Any other suggestions for the break? Or is this an issue?

**Update 1: My page break code in my *.cshtml**

```
  // Worked like this in itext5
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
  // table 
</div>
```

Comment: Html2Pdf is a different product, it's for PHP. The iText 7 add-on is called *pdfHtml*. So solutions 1 and 2 are not relevant for you.

Comment: Ok...  But it is somewhat confusing since there is a "html2pdf" in my nuget package too?Then What would you use ?

Comment: That's just the internal name. The product name is pdfHtml.

Comment: Which element do you apply `page-break-before` to? This css property is actually supported by pdfHTML. E.g. `p {page-break-before: always;}` works and generates a page break as expected. Please post the whole HTML code you are trying to convert to PDF.

Comment: See my edit in question: to the div tag => i embed my style because i didn't got my css working like the way i did in itext5

Comment: This should work for `pdfHTML`. See [this](https://pastebin.com/0Kx474hR) HTML code for an example that works. If  it does not work for you, this is most likely a bug and you should address it to iText sales/support team.

Comment: Guess it is a bug then: First tried to copy a bit from you snippit => no succes. replaced my whole template with yours => still no success. Should have stick wih itext 5...

Comment: You have also asked this question to the iText sales team. You will get an answer via that channel. Alexey: see TSALES-1380.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will report back here.

Comment: Some other tests like adding the break tag to css, and adding an !important tag, aren't working either. Are you sure it is embedded in the itext7.pdfhtml ?`Also This css property is actually supported by pdfHTML.` => Where can i find which are/ aren't supported ?

Comment: Have you got the solution.? facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research and for those who are in the same situation.

In the example provided in "Chapter 2: Defining styles with CSS" of itext, the "width" property is present. So i just added width: 100% like "" and it worked.