# How to add customised tag to add a pagebreak in html2pdf conversion using iText 7

Tags: java, html2pdf, itext7

```
<div>
<h1>
This is a custom tag worker sample.
</h1>
<br>
<h1>
This is a custom tag worker sample.</h1>
<break/>
<h1>
This is a custom tag worker sample after page break.</h1>
<break/>
<h3>This is last page</h3>
</div>
```

According to the above html, I want the generated pdf to contain a pagebreak of type next_page wherever there is a break tag.

Comment: Why not using `page-break-before: always` CSS property?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674882/page-break-in-itext7-in-method-htmltopdf

Comment: The page-break-before: always works for the newest snapshot of pdfHTML add -on. Thank You @AlexeySubach