# Add header in pdf

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

I am making a simple pdf generation react application,

**Libraries used:**

- [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)
- [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)

The following is the code that I have tried,

**index.js:**

```
<div className="App">
  <button onClick={exportToPdf}>Export</button>
  <div id="toRender">
    .
    .
    .
     Some lengthy content
    .
    .
    .
   </div>
</div>
```

So here on click over the export button, the pdf generation happens.

```
  const exportToPdf = () => {
    let elem = document.getElementById("toRender");
    elem.scrollIntoView();
    h2c(elem).then((canvas) => {
      const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
      //console.log(`"data:image/png;base64,${img}"`)

      const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm");

      const imgWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;

      let position = 10;

      pdf.addImage(img, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, 100, 90);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      // pdf.rect(5, 5, 200, 285).line(5, 45, 205, 45);
      // pdf.line(3, 35, imgWidth - 3, 35)

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        pdf.addPage();
        pdf.addImage(img, "PNG", 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        // pdf.rect(5, 5, 200, 285).line(5, 45, 205, 45);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }

      //pdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0)
      pdf.save("export.pdf");
    });
  };
```

The pdf generation works fine.

I need to implement header for all the dynamically generated pages. I have tried adding like `pdf.text("<header> Some header content </header>")`, but it doesn't work.

How to add header in all the pages while generating pdf?

[image: Edit generate pdf with jspdf (forked)]

Comment: Maybe the text is under the image. Did you add the `pdf.text` line after `pdf.addPage()` or after `pdf.addImage()`

Comment: @dehart, After ```pdf.addPage()``` ..

Comment: Then your image probably gets drawn over your text. comment out `addImage()` to be sure

Comment: Tried but no luck.. Could you please help me with a solution by forking my above codesandbox?

Comment: I did, the text() function only works with x and y parameters. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done with this feature in a Vue project lately. I also needed to add a logo at the header of all of my pages. There are a couple of different ways to do that;

Before I start, here is my solution how I split my pages from the others while putting a header on the header;

1. I set these styles;

```css
.pdf-page__pagebreak {
  page-break-after: always;
  clear: both;
}
```

2. I used the `pdf-page__pagebreak` element wherever I need to split the page.

```html
<div v-if="section.pagebreak">
  <div class="pdf-page__pagebreak" />
  <Logo class="pdf-page__logo" />
</div>
```

**Strike**: I implemented this approach because I created the pdf view in HTML (instead of creating with fully JS) as I also need to show these elements on the screen to the user in my case. You can also have another approach by having a loop to set a header for all pages if you create your pdf fully with javascript.

Here are some best practices for your case;

1. https://haensel.pro/allgemein/jspdf-html2pdf-loop-through-pages-and-add-content
2. https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/21#issuecomment-447028134

On the other hand, I found a couple of content yesterday to add a header, but those didn't work for me. I also shared links below; it may help a bit;

- https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/21
- [Page break in Html2Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117788/page-break-in-html2pdf)
- https://haensel.pro/allgemein/jspdf-html2pdf-loop-through-pages-and-add-content

Answer (score 0):

The `pdf.text()` function requires an additional `x` and `y` parameter:
http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text

use it like this:

`pdf.text('Some header content', 10, 10);`

If you want to have the header in every additional page add this line in the while() loop as well.